# NSDate Extension not working

Tags: ios, swift3, nsdate

This is a piece of code that was working in earlier version of swift. It is now giving an error (Cannot convert value of type 'NSDate' to type 'NSDate.Date' in coercion)

```
extension NSDate {
struct Date {
    static let formatterISO8601: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.ISO8601)! as Calendar
        formatter.locale = NSLocale.current
        formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0) as TimeZone!
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"
        return formatter
    }()
}


var formattedISO8601: String { return Date.formatterISO8601.string(from: self as Date) }
```

}

Comment: Regarding Swift 3 your code is a mess. Please use the native Swift 3 structs `Date` (which causes the error because it clashes with your `Date` struct !), `Calendar`, `Locale`, `TimeZone`.

Comment: This seems like it should be an extension of `DateFormatter` and not `Date` (apart from the fact that the `Date` type already exists and you're declaring a new type here…). Also, depending on your deployment target, you could use the `NSISO8601DateFormatter` class introduced in the latest release.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is that in Swift 3 there is already a structure define with named [`Date`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/date).

So what you can do is change your struct name to `MyDate` or something else and you all set to go.

Also it is better if you use new `Date`, `Calendar` and `TimeZone` instead of `NSDate`, `NSCalendar` and `NSTimeZone`.

Or make extension of `Date` like this way.

```
extension Date {

    static let formatterISO8601: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.locale = Locale.current
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"
        return formatter
    }()

    var formattedISO8601: String { return Date.formatterISO8601.string(from: self) }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extensions for both NSDate and Date.

```
extension Date {
    static let formatterISO8601: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.ISO8601)! as Calendar
        formatter.locale = NSLocale.current
        formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0) as TimeZone!
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"
        return formatter
    }()

    func formattedISO8601() -> String {
        return Date.formatterISO8601.string(from: self)
    }
}

extension NSDate {
    func formattedISO8601() -> String {
        return Date.formatterISO8601.string(from: self as Date)
    }
}
```

And use it like this ...

```
// NSDate
let nsdate = NSDate.init()
let formattedDate = nsdate.formattedISO8601()

// Date
let date = Date.init()
let formattedNsDate = date.formattedISO8601()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   extension Date {

    static let formatterISO8601: DateFormatter = {
      let formatter = DateFormatter()
      formatter.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.ISO8601)! as Calendar
      formatter.locale = NSLocale.current
      formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0) as TimeZone!
      formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"
      return formatter
    }()



  var formattedISO8601: String { return Date.formatterISO8601.string(from: self)
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok its working but there is already a `Date` Structure and you are making another struct with it

Comment: Now its look ok also ignore to use nstimezone and nscalendar in swift 3

Comment: agreed @NiravD.